# サインアップ時のメール送信が意図した通り動作しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

サインアップ(devise)した時に、登録したメールアドレスにメッセージを送られるようにしたいが、登録時に止まってしまい、送ることができない状態にいます。
もしわかる方がいらしたら、教えて頂きたいです。

**問題：登録を押した際に起きたエラー(上の動作の後に)**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 845ms (ActiveRecord: 52.6ms)

Net::SMTPFatalError (555 5.5.2 Syntax error. p136sm891772lfp.86 - gsmtp
):
  app/models/tourist.rb:13:in `send_welcome_mail'
```

**Terminal結果**

```
TouristMailer#tourist_welcome_mail: processed outbound mail in 47.6ms

Sent mail to <@tourist.email> (545.9ms)
Date: Sat, 04 May 2019 14:28:54 +0300
From: chancetochance2018@gmail.com
To: <@tourist.email>
Message-ID: <5ccd7776e7305_ab733fbfc403e49010004a@ishiwatadohiroshi-no-MacBook-Air.local.mail>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=E3=81=8A=E5=95=8F=E3=81=84=E5=90=88=E3=82=8F=E3=81=9B?=
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5ccd7776e1b11_ab733fbfc403e49099912";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_5ccd7776e1b11_ab733fbfc403e49099912
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

SGlybyDmp5jjgYvjgonllY/jgYTlkIjjgo/jgZvjgYzjgYLjgorjgb7jgZfj
gZ/jgIINCg0K44O744GK5ZWP44GE5ZCI44KP44GbDQoNCg0K

----==_mimepart_5ccd7776e1b11_ab733fbfc403e49099912
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>=0D
  <body>=0D
    <!doctype html>=0D
<html lang=3D"ja">=0D
<head>=0D
  <meta content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8" />=0D
</head>=0D
<body>=0D
  <h2>Hiro =E6=A7=98</h2>=0D
  <hr />=0D
  <p>=0D
    =E3=81=93=E3=82=93=E3=81=AB=E3=81=A1=E3=81=AF=EF=BC=81 Hiro=E3=81=95=E3=
=82=93=EF=BC=81</p>=0D
  <hr />=0D
</body>=0D
</html>=0D
=0D
  </body>=0D
</html>=0D

----==_mimepart_5ccd7776e1b11_ab733fbfc403e49099912--

   (9.5ms)  ROLLBACK

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 845ms (ActiveRecord: 52.6ms)

Net::SMTPFatalError (555 5.5.2 Syntax error. p136sm891772lfp.86 - gsmtp):
app/models/tourist.rb:13:in `send_welcome_mail'
```

**実際のコード**

views/tourist_welcome_mailer.html.erb

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <h2><%= @tourist.name %> 様</h2>
  <hr />
  <p>
    こんにちは！ <%= @tourist.name %>さん！</p>
  <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

mailers/tourist_mailer.rb

```
class TouristMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: '<chancetochance2018@gmail.com>'

    def tourist_welcome_mail(tourist)
      @tourist = tourist
      mail(
        from: '<chancetochance2018@gmail.com>',
        to:    '<'+'@tourist.email'+'>',
        subject: 'お問い合わせ'
        )
    end
 end
```

model/tourist.rb

```
after_create :send_welcome_mail

def send_welcome_mail
  TouristMailer.tourist_welcome_mail(self).deliver_now
end
```

config/development.rb

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                  587,
    domain:               'smtp.gmail.com',
    user_name:            'chancetochance2018@gmail.com',
    password:             '???????????',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto:  true
  }
```

Comment: `'<'+'@tourist.email'+'>'`だと変数が展開されてませんので `"<#{@tourist.email}>"` に変更するとどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！実行することができました。

Comment: 良かったです。回答として投稿しましたので、回答済みのチェックをお願いします。チェックしてあると他の方が一覧を見るだけで回答済みだと判断できますので。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'<'+'@tourist.email'+'>'
```

だと変数が展開されてませんので

```
"<#{@tourist.email}>"
```

か

```
'<' + @tourist.email + '>'
```

に変更してください。

Answer (score 2):

GmailのSMTPサーバを使ってメールを送る際、メールのヘッダにあるアドレスは <> でくくる必要があるようです。<>でくくっていないので書式が違うから、555 5.5.2 Syntax errorが出たのだと思われます。

詳細な情報と修正方法は、[CakePHPで標準のメールコンポーネントでGmailのSMTPサーバーを使う。](https://tomoya.hatenadiary.org/entry/20100804/1280900579)
の記事が参考になると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。見てみます。

Comment: この場合は、tourist_mailer.rbでのgmailに<>をすればよろしいでしょうか？     （もしそうであれば、535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more atのエラーが出てしまいました。)

Comment: リンクを張った先の記事を丁寧に読むと、$this->Email->to、$this->Email->from、$this->Email->replyToの３か所でメールアドレスを<>でくくっていて、”// ここ”というコメントがついています。mailers/tourist_mailer.rbの「to:    '@tourist.email',」の部分を「to : '<' + '@tourist.email' + '>'」というような感じに修正してみてください。「from:」の行はメールアドレスを<>でくくったものになっているので、そのままで。

Comment: ・エラーが出ていたので、deliver_nowを追加しました。・プロセスは順調に行なっているのですが、まだ止まってしまっています。to:'<'+'@tourist.email'+'>'に追加してみたのですが、このエラーが引き続き出てきました。Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2125ms (ActiveRecord: 7.9ms)

Net::SMTPFatalError (555 5.5.2 Syntax error. v22sm352163lje.44 - gsmtp
):
  app/models/tourist.rb:13:in `send_welcome_mail'

Comment: 初期の質問は「555 5.5.2 Syntax errorが出た」という話だったと記憶していますが、今は「535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.」という全く違うエラーの話ですよね。　以前の質問が何だったのかが判らないようはやりかたで質問を改変されたのでは、回答は不可能ですよ。　ちゃんと意味が分かるような質問を書けるだけの日本語の知識と能力をつけることを強くお勧めします。　プログラム言語よりも、日本語が大切です。　それを忘れたら、永遠にまともなコードを書けないまま終わりかねません。

Comment: 私自身が動作に着いていけていない状態で、質問をしたことにより、動作の状態がわからない説明になってしまい、誠に申し訳ないです。最初の投稿の際には、555 5.5.2 Syntax errorのエラーが出てたのですが、教えていただいた内容を追加した直後には、535-5.7.8のエラーが出たのですが、再び、上記の内容を追加したのに555 5.5.2 Syntax errorに戻ってしまいました。そして、今現在は、Net::SMTPFatalError (555 5.5.2 Syntax error. s3sm888028lfc.25 - gsmtp
):
  app/models/tourist.rb:13:in `send_welcome_mail'のエラーが出ている状態です。